# Libgdx Particle effect - reset scale

Tags: android, libgdx

in my game I'm scaling water particle effect with torpedo. I'm using ParticleEffectPool. My problem is that when I free effect and obtain new one scale constist same as when I free it.

My code:
My Game class:

```
pool_waveLeft = new ParticleEffectPool((ParticleEffect) main.manager.get("particle/waveLeft.p"), 5, 20);
```

My torpedo init function:

```
waveLeft = game.pool_waveLeft.obtain();
waveLeft.start();
```

My torpedo update function:

```
(float ParticleScale = 1;)
ParticleScale -= 0.00007f / (0.01666666f / Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
waveLeft.scaleEffect(ParticleScale);
waveLeft.setPosition(getX() + (getWidth() * 0.15f), getY() + (getHeight() * 0.95F));
waveLeft.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
waveLeft.draw(batch);
```

When is torpedo destroyed:

```
((PooledEffect) waveLeft).free();
```

Comment: This was a long time bug, fixed very recently. Until LibGDX 1.9.7 comes out, you'll have to use LibGDX 1.9.7-SNAPSHOT to avoid the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the scale of the particle effect when you create it

```
waveLeft = game.pool_waveLeft.obtain();
waveLeft.scaleEffect(1f);
waveLeft.start();
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: Try adding a waveLeft.reset(true); This should reset the scaling too.

Comment: There is no parameter for reset method.

Comment: You're right, its only in the normal particle effect.

Comment: Do all of this particle effect shrink over time? if they do, you should edit the particle effect parameters to shrink over time instead of scaling the whole effect as the scaling is meant as a permanent size change.